# how to alter alt tag of images inside a similar class dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, drupal

So use case is this that i have a block where i am printing images inside a similar content with similar class Now i want to change the alt just by adding book cover at the end but when i run the code book cover is rendered more than once is there a way i can fix this?

```
/* changing alt tags of featured items */
    $(".featured-item").each( function () {
       var alt_val = $(this).find('img').attr("alt");
       console.log(alt_val);
       $(this).find('img').attr("alt", "Book cover:"+alt_val+"");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **use one variable (me) for next usings.**
- **Add a class "done-with-alt" after done your alt attribute. If the element has class "done-with-alt" continue.**

**Check and skip:** if ($(this).hasClass("done-with-alt")) return true;

**Done after :** $(this).addClass("done-with-alt");

**Your new code can be:**

```
/* changing alt tags of featured items */
    $(".featured-item").each( function () {
       var me = $(this);
       if (me.hasClass("done-with-alt")) return true;

       
       var alt_val = me.find('img').attr("alt");
       console.log(alt_val);
       me.find('img').attr("alt", "Book cover:"+alt_val+"");
     
       me.addClass("done-with-alt");
    });
```

---

If **jQuery can not update your element** (.featured-item), you can wrap this interval around and check that every 100 ms for about 1000 ms long:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){

    /* changing alt tags of featured items */
    $(".featured-item").each( function () {
       var me = $(this);
       if (me.hasClass("done-with-alt")) return true;

       
       var alt_val = me.find('img').attr("alt");
       console.log(alt_val);
       me.find('img').attr("alt", "Book cover:"+alt_val+"");
     
       me.addClass("done-with-alt");
    });
},100);

setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
},1000);
```

*Not good code because the interval/checks have to be stopped. So this code use a triggered timeout to clear the interval (which must be done hopefully after 1000 milliseconds).*

Comment: Thankyou sir I will test it and let you know.

Comment: This works but jQuery does not have continue keyword so put return true and it works fine. Thankyou.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference between two codes because both of them worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, yes it must be return true. The first code runs only once (no looping). Use this if it worked. Sometimes jQuery can not change the elements. So the second (interval) code check every 0.1 seconds for the elements in the each-loop. That's why the second code has a timeout to stop the endless looping.